# Add label to card (the label is from another board)

Tags: api, trello

I have a *label* that I created on board B1, and a *card* on B2.
Now I want to add the *label* to the *card*.

When I `POST` the id of the label to `/1/cards/<cardid>/idLabels` I get a 404. 
When I `POST` the id of a label that was created on B1: success.

However when I look at the `labels` resource of the *card*, every label includes a board ID, and IDs are globally unique.

Can I add a label from a different board, or doesn't Trello work like that?

Answer (score 1):

Every label from every board has got a different ID. So you cannot use same label ID for more than 1 board.

I would advise to

1. create a new label if needed
2. if you are using generic labels which can be defined by color (yellow, orange, red, blue, green, etc) you can get their unique ids by calling `/boards/BOARD_ID/labels` and looping though the json until you find the right color name.